# Burning Linux ISO to DVD and making it bootable

Tags: windows-xp, iso-image

I just downloaded the Fedora 14 Live-Desktop ISO and used CDBurnerXP to burn the image to a DVD. For some reason the first time I burned the image nothing showed up on the DVD when I accessed it even though CDBurnerXP said it had successfully burned to the disk. I did it again and the ISO shows up on the disk (I don't think this is right, should it be the files inside the image that show up on disk or the image file??). The problem now is my dell PC can't find the ISO when I try to boot from it. I get an error saying it can't boot from the CD.

I have verified the ISO image as directed from the Fedora website. My question is how do I make a bootable CD from a Fedora Live-Desktop ISO? How can I verify that the ISO was written to the CD correctly and has anyone had any issues booting from a CD using a Dell desktop (I'm not at home at the moment so I can't check what model it is but its old enough, I've had it for about 5 years).

EDIT: All that needed to be done was to burn the image to CD as an image and not a data file. The first three times failed, I'm not sure if this was because of faulty DVD's or if the write speed was too high (16x). I put in a new DVD and changed the write speed to 8x, the image was then properly burned to the disk without any errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into whatever tool you're using to burn it and burn it as an image, not as a file.

Comment: Thanks for that, I realize now that I must have burned it as a data file but I'm sure that the first time I burned it as an image and nothing showed up on the disk. If the image is burned correctly should the contents of the image show up on the disk?

Comment: Yes, and the disc will be bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you burn an .iso to DVD on Fedora 28 with a DVD writer in the /dev/sr0 device location:

```
growisofs -speed=2 -dvd-compat  -Z  /dev/sr0=kubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

where:

-speed=2 makes certain the burn doesn't go too fast to write all data properly; remember the disk is flying around at speed and you need to write sectors with data that doesn't slow down during the vital write. Anything that can stall your process may effect the write operations.

-Z  /dev/sr0=kubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso is the device and the target .iso all in one command flag.

-dvd-compat  Provides maximum  media  compatibility  with  DVD-ROM/-Video.  In write-once  DVD+R  or DVD-R context this results in unappendable               recording (closed disk). In DVD+RW context it instructs the logical unit to explicitly burn [otherwise optional] lead-out.